# Why does giving addArcWithCenter a startAngle of 0 degrees make it start at 90 degrees?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, core-animation, uibezierpath

I'm creating a `CAShapeLayer` to use as a mask for a `UIView`'s layer. I'm using a `UIBezierPath` to draw the shape layer. It's working fine, except I'm getting some odd results when I draw. The geometry is not behaving as expected. I'm trying to draw simple "pie slice" in the upper right corner:

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)

...

// "layer" refer's to the UIView's root layer

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.frame =
    layer.presentationLayer ? 
    ((CAGradientLayer *)layer.presentationLayer).bounds : layer.bounds;
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

CGFloat maskLayerWidth = maskLayer.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat maskLayerHeight = maskLayer.bounds.size.height;
CGPoint maskLayerCenter = 
    CGPointMake(maskLayerWidth/2,maskLayerHeight/2);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path moveToPoint:maskLayerCenter];

[path addArcWithCenter:maskLayerCenter radius:(maskLayerWidth/2)
startAngle:degreesToRadians(0) endAngle:degreesToRadians(90) clockwise:YES];

[path closePath];


maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;

layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

The end result is that a pie slice is drawn in the lower right corner. The first point of the arc is drawn at the 90 degrees, then down to 180. Why does it do this even though I'm using 0 and 90 degree angles?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This image comes straight from [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:).

[image]

And there is a discussion of how it works (given the default coordinate system)

> **Discussion**
>   This method adds the specified arc beginning at the current point. The created arc lies on the perimeter of the specified circle. When drawn in the default coordinate system, the start and end angles are based on the unit circle shown in **Figure 1**. For example, specifying a start angle of 0 radians, an end angle of π radians, and setting the clockwise parameter to `YES` draws the bottom half of the circle. However, specifying the same start and end angles but setting the `clockwise` parameter set to `NO` draws the top half of the circle.

This is how the angles work for `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`. If that isn't what you are seeing then you are calculating your angles incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at **Figure 1** in the [bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) documentation: For a "pie slice" in the upper right corner
you have to use the parameters

```
startAngle:degreesToRadians(-90) endAngle:0 clockwise:YES
```

(The reason is that the default coordinate system on iOS has a x-axis pointing to the right, and a y-axis pointing down.)