# Round start and end of the line for a circle with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, swift5

I have a case very similar to [Draw circle with UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992714/draw-circle-with-uibezierpath)
I have this `path` with `UIBezierPath`

[image]

Just taking focus in the gray circle:

```
grayView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth * 0.15,
                                        y: 150,
                                        width: screenWidth * 0.7,
                                        height: screenWidth * 0.7 ))

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = 32

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addCircle(center: CGPoint(x: grayView.bounds.width / 2,
                                       y: grayView.bounds.height / 2),
                                        radius: screenWidth/3.5,
                                        startAngle: 125,
                                        circlePercentage: 0.8)

        layer.path = path.cgPath

        grayView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        grayView.setNeedsLayout()
```

What I'm trying to do is modify the start and the end of the curved gray line and make a rounded start/end, like this:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`lineCap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521905-linecap) of the shape layer to [`.round`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayerlinecap/1521916-round).