# CGPathAddArc clockwise and anticlockwise confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, cgpath

Below is the code which draws the Arc from `M_PI/2` to `M_PI`.

```
CGContextRef contet=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect), CGRectGetMidX(rect),  M_PI/2.0,M_PI, YES);

CGContextAddPath(contet, path);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contet, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(content);
```

Below is the drawing of the above code.

[image]

I was expecting it to draw it in the empty or missing part , as its clockwise. I referred to this answer [Why does giving addArcWithCenter a startAngle of 0 degrees make it start at 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192254/why-does-giving-addarcwithcenter-a-startangle-of-0-degrees-make-it-start-at-90-d) but, I don't know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because,in Core Graphics,the origin is at left/bottom

**Flipping horizontally changes clockwise to anti clockwise and vice versa**

You just need to change `clockwise` to `NO` to get what you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just pay more attention to the method you used.

```
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect), CGRectGetMidX(rect),  M_PI/2.0,M_PI, NO);
```

Just change the last parameter to NO, you will get what you want, it can control the drawing direction.